# Why isn't my thread starting back up when the Condition object is notified/released?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-3.6

This question pertains to Python 3.6.

I have a piece of code which has a thread from the threading library running, as well as the program's main thread. Both threads access an object that is not threadsafe, so I have them locking on a `Condition` object before using the object. The thread I spawned only needs to access/update that object once every 5 minutes, so there's a 5 minute sleep timer in the loop.

Currently, the main thread never gets a hold of the lock. When the second thread releases the `Condition` and starts waiting on the `sleep()` call, the main thread never wakes up/acquires the lock. It's as if the main thread has died.

```
class Loader:
    def __init__(self, q):
        ...
        self.queryLock = threading.Condition()
        ...
        thread = Thread(target=self.threadfunc, daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        ...
        self.run()

    def threadfunc(self):
        ...
        while True:
            self.queryLock.acquire()
            [critical section #1]
            self.queryLock.notify()
            self.queryLock.release()
            sleep(300)

    def run(self):
        ...
        while True:
            ...
            self.queryLock.acquire()
            [critical section #2]
            self.queryLock.notify()
            self.queryLock.release()
            ...
```

Comment: A possible issue is that you've used a Condition where really a basic Lock would suffice. According to the docs if you don't provide any parameters when initialising Condition it creates an underlying RLock (reentrant lock) to use wher really a basic Lock is all you need. Try initialising the Condition as Condition(lock=Lock()) or just replace it with a Lock

Comment: Can you confirm that no thread ever waits for the condition? Also, can you show us the real code for the main thread? With the `...`, I can't tell what the main thread is actually doing most of the time. Also, what happens during the `[critical section #2]` code? It matters what the thread is doing while it holds the lock. Are you saying *neither* thread gets the lock? Or are you saying that one thread keeps getting the lock over and over and the other doesn't get a chance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't really need to use a Condition. It appears that a simple `Lock` would get the job done in your case. You don't actually verify that some condition is met and you don't use the Condition's special method `wait()`.

---

That being said, regarding the code you provided, it seems that your main thread is too "quick", and re-acquires the lock before the other thread gets a chance.
Here is a slightly modified version of your code in which the main thread is waiting a bit, giving the other thread a chance, and it successfully acquires the lock and continue.

```
class Loader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queryLock = threading.Condition()
        thread = Thread(target=self.threadfunc, daemon=True)
        thread.start()
        self.run()
    
    def threadfunc(self):
        while True:
            self.queryLock.acquire()
            print("critical section 1")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.queryLock.notify()
            self.queryLock.release()
            time.sleep(5)
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.queryLock.acquire()
            print("critical section 2")
            time.sleep(2)
            self.queryLock.notify()
            self.queryLock.release()
            print("main is waiting a bit")
            time.sleep(1)


Loader()
```

Race conditions are fun :)

Comment: Re, "...your main thread is too 'quick'", there's a name for that; "starvation." It's what we say when patterns of locking and/or signalling contrive to make one (or more) thread(s) always late for dinner. The main thread in this example is _starving_ the new thread.